# The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer called `ProjectSerializer`. It has a file field. The view is:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

When I post data from html form in django rest framework, it works the file gets uploaded. But when I use the raw data as json and send data by using url of the file content the error arises:

```
{
    "project_question_content_url": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ]
}
```

The problem is I am using jquery to provide the url. But before sending the url from jquery I tested in the api. It gives the error while providing the url.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use **multipart/form-data**? See this link https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-submit-a-multipart-form/

You did not show your the serializer, the form, or the js code itself.